# Khan Academy API: HTTP Response was too large python

Tags: python, http, oauth, rauth, khan-academy

This is my first question so bear with me. I tried to look for some solutions prior to posting. Yay me.

I am using the Khan academy API and have customized a few things in my python rauth-based authentication script. It works.

However, When I try to make a call like: /api/v1/user/exercises?email=email@email.com the return response either times out or gives me the message "HTTP response was too large: 36753303. The limit is: 33554432."

Most other calls come in fine and I can see all of the json data coming in. Those calls perhaps do not return as much data.

This program is running locally on my personal machine and has not been deployed onto a dedicated server.

Is the limitation on my end or a limitation of Khan Academy? How can I increase the limit of the data being read in?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a software engineer at Khan Academy.

Sorry for the trouble, this was a limitation of the API endpoint, but I just made a change that should fix it. See this GitHub issue for details:

https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/issues/94